# DAX RANKX Within Group

Tags: powerbi, dax, rank

I have a table called `CarSales` with the following sample data:

[image: 1]

I already have a measure that ranks all Brands by sales:

**`Rank = RANKX(ALL('CarSales'[Brand]),[NetSales])`**

However, I need another measure/column **"`Rank(Country)`" ** which ranks the Brands within the Country group (without having to display the Country group in the table)

Thanks

Comment: Please paste sample data as text.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following measure:

```
=
VAR ThisCountry =
    MIN( CarSales[Country] )
RETURN
    RANKX(
        FILTER( ALLSELECTED( CarSales ), 'CarSales'[Country] = ThisCountry ),
        [NetSales]
    )
```